# Install packages with Conda for a second Python installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I recently installed Anaconda in my Windows. I did that to use some packages from some specific channels required by an application that is using Python 3.5 as its scripting language.

I adjusted my PATH variable to use Conda, pointing to the Python environment of the particular program, but now I would like to use Conda as well for a different Python installation that I have on my Windows.

When installing Anaconda then it isn't asking for a Python version to be related to. So, how can I use Conda to install into the other Python installation. Both Python installations are 'physical' installations - not virtual in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the other python installation and create different conda environments, that is what `conda` is great at. 
Using `conda` from your anaconda installation to manage packages from another, independent python installation is not possible and not very feasible.

Something like this could serve your needs:

1. Create one env for python 3.5 `conda create -n py35 python=3.5`
2. Create one env for some other python version you would like to use, e.g. 3.6: `conda create -n py36 python=3.6`
3. Use `conda activate py35`, `conda deactivate`, `conda activate py36` to switch between your virtual environments.

Comment: I feared this answer would come...
You are most certainly right with it and in my case it will most likely work. But what if you have two different applications, both with Python as their scripting environment. Both will install their own 'physical' environment and only one can be fulled by conda...

Comment: Most stuff I have come across let you choose the python interpreter during installation or similar instead of installing their own distribution. Do you have an example?